# Set up probability question.

Tags: probability, problem-solving

Can someone show me how to set this up? Asking for help on how to work this, not asking for the answer.

Question:
Assume that P(A) = 0.5, P(A∩C) = 0.18, P(C) = 0.4, P(B) = 0.4, P(A∩B∩C) = 0.08, P(B∩C) = 0.16, and P(A∩B) = 0.21. Calculate the following probabilities:

b. P(A'∩(B∪C))

Comment: Your newly edited version removed the original question and replaced it with something vague and incorrect. I suggest rolling it back to the previous version. I've deleted my answer as it no longer applies.

Comment: Sorry I'm new to the site about 15min worth of using it. I was trying to follow suggestions in the FAQs about asking a question to help me understand my homework without asking the actual question.

Comment: rolled back to original question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that
$$P(A' \cap (B \cup C)) = P(A' \cap B) + P(A' \cap C) - P(A' \cap B \cap C)$$
The three terms on the RHS can be computed as follows:
$$P(A' \cap B) = P(B) - P(A \cap B)$$
$$P(A' \cap C) = P(C) - P(A \cap C)$$
$$P(A' \cap B \cap C) = P(B \cap C) - P(A \cap B \cap C)$$